# Detecting puntuation errors when parsing sentences

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm currently testing out stanfordNLP and more precisely coreNLP to parse a bunch of reviews. Right during my first test I came accross a small problem with sentence detection / splitting as my input string had a punctuation error.

Here's the input :

> We took two rooms and found the hotel delightful.  The staff was very
>   helpful.We didn't have the breakfast because we lacked time.

As you can see the punctuation in the second sentence lacks a white space after the dot and therefore coreNLP did not detect that there was 3 sentences but 2 instead and treated the token "helpful.We" as Noun.

Is there a way to detect and correct such punctuation errors either during pre-processing or otherwise, so that coreNLP does detect the 3 sentences corretly ?

Are there any other caveats similar to this one I should be looking for ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no utility for doing this automatically within CoreNLP. The sentence splitter is a rule-based tool that doesn't take into account this problem.

You can fix it with preprocessing in several different ways. You'll have to pick the route that best fits your use case / need of precision:

- brute-force (`replace('.', '. ')`)
- rule-based (`replace('.', '. ') unless preceding_token =~ /Mr|Mrs|Ms/`, etc.)
- probabilistic (build a classifier which evaluates each potential sentence-final character as actually indicating a sentence final or not)